# Unity set player Y-rotation equal to that of the camera Y-rotaion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, euler-angles

I need to set directly the Y-Rotation of the player to be equal to the `Camera.main` Y-Rotation I have searched a lot but can't find the answer.

I know it is simple but I can't manage it.

**Edit:** I tried this code

`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles);`

But it set the rotation of the whole rotation of the object equal to the rotation of the camera X,Y,and Z but what I want is to set only the y rotation.Thanks for help.

**Edit2:**[image: PlayerImage]

> I forgot to say whay I am using this in I am making a VR Game so when the player rotates his head the camera rotates successfully.
>
> **Note:** Why I want to do that? because when my player has to move forward it has to have the same y rotation of the camera.

Comment: Can you provide a diagram, or some screenshots of what you're trying to achieve? It's possible that setting the rotation directly may not actually be the best/simplest course of action here.

Comment: @Serlite I have edited question check it please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
```